# Can't update my database record in codeigniter, no error is appearing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm quite new to php and there's no error appearing but appereantly, can't update my data in the database.

[The controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drTLU.png)

```
  public function update_user_view() { 
     $this->load->helper('form'); 
     $user_id = $this->uri->segment('3'); 
     $query = $this->db->get_where("users",array("user_id"=>$user_id));
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $data['old_user_id'] = $user_id; 
     $this->load->view('user_edit',$data); 
  } 

  public function update_user(){ 
     $this->load->model('user_model');

     $data = array(  
        'user_id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'), 
        'nickname' => $this->input->post('nickname'), 
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'), 
        'hadd' => $this->input->post('hadd'), 
        'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'), 
        'cpnum' => $this->input->post('cpnum'), 
        'comment' => $this->input->post('comment') 

     ); 

     $old_user_id = $this->input->post('old_user_id'); 
     $this->user_model->update($data,$old_user_id); 

     $query = $this->db->get("users"); 
     $data['records'] = $query->result(); 
     $this->load->view('user_view',$data); 
  }
```

[the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH3C1.png)

```
<?php 
   class User_model extends CI_Model {

      function __construct() { 
         parent::__construct(); 
      } 

      public function insert($data) { 
         if ($this->db->insert("users", $data)) { 
            return true; 
         } 
      } 

      public function delete($user_id) { 
         if ($this->db->delete("users", "user_id = ".$user_id)) { 
            return true; 
         } 
      } 

      public function update($data,$old_user_id) { 
         $this->db->set($data); 
         $this->db->where("user_id", $old_user_id); 
         $this->db->update("users", $data); 
      } 
   } 
?>
```

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` after update and see what's the problem

Comment: @FastSnail nothing happened.

Comment: nothing?you should see the actual mysql query

Comment: @FastSnail it shows SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '100' which is the primary key and the value , of the data i'm trying to edit.

Comment: did you echo it after the `$this->user_model->update($data,$old_user_id);` line ?

Comment: @FastSnail I've tried both of them, after putting it below $this->user_model->update($data,$old_user_id); , it displays SELECT * FROM `users`.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
$this->db->where("user_id", $old_user_id); 
$this->db->update("users",$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$this->db->set($data);` from update method of model. This is not required as update query data section is used to set table records.